# I have problems, my component can not update the property of the second component - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

[My example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hIQn.gif)

The ownership of a component is not updated

```
<draggable v-model="questions" :move="moveQuestion">
    <question-create v-for="preg, index in questions" :data-question="preg" :key="index">
    </question-create>
</draggable>
```

the `<question-create>` component has the following

props['dataQuestion']

```
<dropdown-select :options="listDropdown" :selectedId="dataQuestion.input_id" @returnSelected="selectedDropdown($event)">
</dropdown-select>
```

Does not update the property `:selectedId` with

```
dataQuestion.input_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Props are case-sensitive and need to be [kebab-case, not camelCase](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#camelCase-vs-kebab-case). The reason for this is because Vue template syntax wants to follow the syntax of standard HTML as closely as possible.

```
<dropdown-select
  :options="listDropdown"
  :selected-id="dataQuestion.input_id"
  @returnSelected="selectedDropdown($event)" />
```

Comment: Does not update the property :selected-id="dataQuestion.input_id". My example https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hIQn.gif

Comment: @LuisMiguelFeijooValeriano can you provide more context for your code?